# How much is the scale of startup packages in the UK universities?

Tags: funding, faculty-application, tenure-track, united-kingdom

I've been offered a tenure-track position (organic chemistry) in Cornell University and I was able to negotiate a startup package of close to $1 million. I've just been invited for an interview for a similar position in a UK university. I decided not to give a definite answer to Cornell before completing the latter interview to have the chance to choose between two offers.

However, a friend of mine advised that the US universities are much better for starting an academic career. The job advertisement of the UK position mentioned *generous startup package*, but my friend tells that the startup packages in the UK are ridiculous in comparison with the US. And I should apply for a startup fund in the scale of $100K through a detailed proposal to the national funding agencies. He concluded that, in the best case scenario, I can get a fraction of my negotiated startup package in Cornell. Then, I must immediately accept the Cornell offer.

My question is, how is the scale of startup packages in the UK?

Comment: Your conclusion that you 'must immediately accept the Cornell offer' doesn't follow from what you've said. Also, for a permanent position, you might want to consider which country you want to live in.

Comment: If you already successfully communicated to Cornell that you want to delay a decision, what harm is there in seeing for yourself what the UK university is going to offer?

Comment: I am not sure if perhaps it may not be standard procedure but..... what if you ask them? They are offering you a job, I see no reason why you should not ask "how much money you are giving me", even if its not directly salary.

Comment: @kora what was the outcome of the situation?